# What's the replacement for UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged

Tags: ios, uikit

Why is UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged deprecated and what is its replacement?  Seems like a normal notification feature that I really need to help my voiceover users.

Is it because they are assuming a voiceover user would have already had voiceover status set in the beginning? Hence using UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()

I can set an observer on UIAccessibilityElementFocused but then I have to do some logic caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It got renamed to [`NSNotificationCenter.Name.UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/2865862-uiaccessibilityvoiceoverstatusdi). Unfortunately, the list of accessibility notifications doesn't mention this one, and the docs for the deprecated name doesn't point to the new one.

Comment: It does point to the new one, but for some reason its only in the framework and not in the official docs found on developer site

Comment: Use UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification in Objective-C